# Querying ManyToMany Association In Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following DQL:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('PARTIAL p.{id, name}', 'p.sku', 'p.name', 'bu.abbreviation AS baseUnit', 'p.price',
            'p.WP', 'p.SP', 'p.MP', 'p.PP', 'p.P3', 's.name as supplier')
        ->join('p.baseUnit', 'bu')
        ->join('p.suppliers', 's')
        ->where('p.active = 1');
```

Product has many suppliers and supplier can be in many products.

The problem in the query is that it returns only 1 supplier.

I tried searching the internet but it always has setParameter on it which i dont need since i just want to get all the products with their related suppliers only without any parameters or whatsoever.

How can I do that in DQL?

Thanks.

Comment: `->from(table, p)`